# JQuery Ajax script won't retrieve info from .php file extension but works with .html extension

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my first attempt at using Jquery AJAX with PHP and I'm stumped.

From all the research I've done it appears that I have everything correctly but, I don't have enough experience or knowledge with this stuff yet to pinpoint the issue.

I have a file called: "signup_UsernameCheck.php", this file does have some php on it but in order to test I've resorted to simply echoing a statement "This is finally working";

When I run the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#username").click(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        $.post("signup_UsernameCheck.php",{username : username},function(data)     {$("#checkExists").html(data);}); 
        $("#checkExists").html(data);
      })
})
```

Nothing happens with this script, yet if I change my file extension from .php to .html, it works fine and displays all the code where it's supposed to, just as text in stead of running the PHP obviously.

The path is obviously correct, as if finds the file perfectly as an .html, I've tried changing the data type and setting it to "text", but even with that parameter it still doesn't "find" the php file.

Comment: Request `signup_UsernameCheck.php` directly with your browser. Does it work?

Comment: If your php file doesn't echo anything then it should not return anything, try directly http"://your_domain/signup_UsernameCheck.php in your browser and see what it returns as hakre said.

Comment: @hakre, I get a "500" inernal server error. If I change the extension to .html, it pulls up fine.

Comment: I've been staring at this for so long that I'm starting to get tunnel vision.

@SheikhHeera, thanks for the heads up, I thought of that before posting and commented out all the php except for this line: echo "This is finally working";
as well just in case I have this line outside of the PHP tags: 
<p>This isn't working</p>.

Is this maybe a permissions issue or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not related to AJAX. It's your server configuration, you must make the PHP script itself work.

From the information you've given, PHP is not properly configured on your server. Contact the technical support of your hosting and solve that issue first before you continue with the javascript part.

Comment: I was kind of thinking that myself, any idea where it would be? PHP works fine on the server, the entire rest of the site runs off of it.

Comment: There can be numerous reasons why you get a 500. If you want to troubleshoot it yourself, start with the error log of your server.

Comment: I checked it out and it ended up beign a permissions thing, due to the way the site runs off of "index.php?public="xxxx", looks like a .php page accessed directly gives a permissions error. I don't have enough knowledge to know why yet, but at least I'm getting the data now, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I've already accepted this answer but just an update to what was happening in case anyone else has this issue:

It did end up being a permissions issue, I had to set that specific to 644 and it fixed it!

Comment: @DavidMorin: Thanks for the follow-up. 0644 is `rw-r--r--`. Do you know which permissions were set when you had the error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was set to 0666, based on the default permissions my text editor assigns to a new file creation. I don't remember now what it was before I changed it, I had messed around with it so much.

Comment: Sometimes if the execute or write bit is set for all, webservers will stop executing it (probably because of security reasons) and give a 500 error instead. With 500 errors, it's best you look into the error log of your webserver, it often contains more information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the data type being sent back from the server isn't being picked up by jQuery.

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").click(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        $.post(
            "signup_UsernameCheck.php",
            {'username': username},
            function(data) {
                $("#checkExists").html(data);
            },
            "html"
        );
    })
});
```

Also - you have one too many `$("#checkExists").html(data);`s

Comment: Thanks, it didn't appear to make a difference. I've tried accessing the file directly on the server as others suggested and I get 500 error so, looks like I need to resolve that first. 

I appreciate the time

Answer (score -1):

Rename signup_UsernameCheck.html to signup_UsernameCheck.php on your server.